# MySQL: Remove duplicate fields based on condition, while retaining all other data

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Need some assistance with a MySQL query.

If the record has a duplicate email field, only keep the row that has STATUS = ACTIVE, while still showing all other records.

```
STATUS      EMAIL
—-------------------------------
active      p1@email.com
—-------------------------------
inactive    p1@email.com
—-------------------------------
active      p2@email.com
—-------------------------------
active      p3@email.com
—-------------------------------
active      p4@email.com
—-------------------------------
Inactive    p4@email.com
```

Comment: Is possible to have duplicate emails and all rows with that email are status = inactive?  If so, how are they handled?

Comment: Please answer the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a few things here:

- Rows without duplicates are not selected.
- Duplicate rows where none are active are not selected.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15b59/4)

Basically a subquery determines which emails are duplicates.  Outer query uses that to selected only those records which have a duplicate email.

```
select *
from
email_status a
inner join
(
  select email, count(email)
  from email_status
  group by email
  having count(email) > 1
) b
on a.email = b.email
where status = 'active'
```

Edit:  Based on the response below the only criteria for selection becomes status = 'active' assuming only 1 record can be active for a given email.  All that is needed is a where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM email_status
WHERE status = 'active'
```

Comment: This is close, but I need to return all non-duplicate rows as well.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: The op also wants the email with status inactive.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use this query to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work:

```
select
(case when count(distinct status) = 2 then 'active'
      else status
 end
) as status,
email
from
yourTableName
group by email;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided two queries:

1. Select Statement. ([DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06de19/1))
2. Delete statement that will remove two line you see in select statement

SELECT a.* FROM agents a
INNER JOIN agents b ON b.EMAIL = a.EMAIL
WHERE a.id <> b.id AND LCASE(a.STATUS)='inactive';

```
DELETE a FROM agents a 
INNER JOIN agents b ON b.EMAIL = a.EMAIL
WHERE a.id <> b.id AND LCASE(a.STATUS)='inactive';
```